# Start linux programs from within Wine?

Tags: linux, process, wine, emulator

I'd like to start `bash` from within `Total Commander` (which itself is running within `Wine`). Any ideas (if there are any at all) how I could do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it to be interactive then run it in a terminal, e.g. `gnome-terminal -e bash`. Just make sure to have the terminal executable accessible on one of your mapped drives.

Comment: I can now start cmd.exe from Totalcmd! How would I start bash? Thanks!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1rUl1.jpg